# number of occurrences of two letters separated by a finite gap

Tags: c++, r, algorithm, rcpp

Lets we have a string `Seq` of size `N` and contain `z` alphabet { A,B,C….}.
I have to perform a function that calculates the number of occurrences of the letter `i` which is separated with `l` letters (gap) from the letter `j`:
Example:

```
I=A, j=T and gap=10
That have to find the number of occurrence of AT,A-T,A--T,A---T,A----T,,,A---------T(- is any alphabet)
```

I used this code for DNA sequence (alphabet `z`=4) and suppose that is N(L*N)
 complexity:

```
inline const short int V (const char x){
    switch(x){
    case 'A':case 'a':
      return 0;
      break;
    case 'C':case 'c':
      return 1;
      break;   
    case 'G':case 'g':
      return 2;
      break;
    default:
      return 3;
    break;  
    }

  }

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  IntegerVector basem(std::string seq ,int gap ,int N){
    IntegerVector res(16);
     short int x=0;
    short int y=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N-gap;i++){
      x=V(seq[i]);
      y=V(seq[i+gap]);
      res[4*x+y]++;
    }
    return res;
  }

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  List basegap (std::string sequence,int x){
    int n=sequence.size();
    List result ;
    for(int j=1;j<x;j++) {
      result.push_back(basem(sequence,j,n));
    }
    return result;
  }
```

> basem:calculate the number of occurence for a gap
>
> basegap: calculate the number of occurence for a gap from 1 to X

Running Example:

```
a
[1] "atgccatcactcagtaaagaagcggccctggttcatgaagcgttagttgcgcgaggactggaaacaccgctgcgcccgcccgtgcatgaaatggataacgaaacgccgaaaagccttattgctggtcatatgaccgaaatcatgcagctgctgaatctcgacctggctgatgacagtttgatggaaacgcggcatcgcatcgctaaaatgtatgtcgatgaaattttctccggtctggattacgccaatttcccgaaaatcaccctcattgaaaacaaaatgaaggtcgatgaaatggtcaccgtccgcgatatcactctgaccagcacctgtgaacaccattttgttaccatcgatggcaaagcgacggtggcctatatcccgaaagattcggtgatcggtctgtcaaaaattaaccgcattgtgcagttctttgcccagcgtccgcaggtgcaggaacgtctgacgcagcaaattcttgttgccgcgctacaaacgctgctgggcaccaataacgtggctgtctcgatcgacgcggtgcattactgcgtgaaggcgcgtggcatccgcgatgcaaccagtgccacgacaacgtcctctcttggtggattgttcaaatccagtcagaatacgcgccacgagtttctgcgcgctgtgcgtcatcacaactga"

 basem(a,5,nchar(a))
 [1] 40 50 42 37 47 46 36 49 45 39 44 39 38 42 45 28 
x<-basegap(a,10)
[[1]]
 [1] 61 38 23 48 48 39 57 35 44 58 28 38 17 44 60 33

[[2]]
 [1] 42 47 43 38 42 49 53 35 44 44 35 44 42 39 37 36

[[3]]
 [1] 50 39 44 37 35 53 44 47 46 41 47 33 39 46 32 36

[[4]]
 [1] 42 54 36 38 54 36 52 36 43 49 41 34 31 39 38 45

[[5]]
 [1] 40 50 42 37 47 46 36 49 45 39 44 39 38 42 45 28

[[6]]
 [1] 42 44 40 42 45 44 44 45 38 44 47 38 44 45 36 28

[[7]]
 [1] 38 44 44 42 44 49 42 42 40 44 42 41 47 40 39 27

[[8]]
 [1] 34 48 47 38 46 49 41 41 47 39 39 42 42 40 40 31

[[9]]
 [1] 43 37 45 42 40 46 56 34 45 57 33 32 40 36 33 44

m<-matrix(unlist(x),nrow=16)
m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]   61   42   50   42   40   42   38   34   43
 [2,]   38   47   39   54   50   44   44   48   37
 [3,]   23   43   44   36   42   40   44   47   45
 [4,]   48   38   37   38   37   42   42   38   42
 [5,]   48   42   35   54   47   45   44   46   40
 [6,]   39   49   53   36   46   44   49   49   46
 [7,]   57   53   44   52   36   44   42   41   56
 [8,]   35   35   47   36   49   45   42   41   34
 [9,]   44   44   46   43   45   38   40   47   45
[10,]   58   44   41   49   39   44   44   39   57
[11,]   28   35   47   41   44   47   42   39   33
[12,]   38   44   33   34   39   38   41   42   32
[13,]   17   42   39   31   38   44   47   42   40
[14,]   44   39   46   39   42   45   40   40   36
[15,]   60   37   32   38   45   36   39   40   33
[16,]   33   36   36   45   28   28   27   31   44
```

My questions are:

1. How to reduce the complexity for this calculation?
2. Are there any ideas to improve this code?

Comment: If you ask for improvement of working code you better go to [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "is separated with `l` letters" Do you mean "less than or equal to `l` letters"?

Comment: l define exactly the number of letters, in otherway,the gap between the `i` and `j`

Comment: Then can you elaborate a little bit more your example `AT,A-T,A--T,A---T,A----T,,,A----------T` where gap is `10`? Should the function return 1?

Comment: I won't to add a running exemple

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to compute the number of gaps of size i between every alphabetical character (including itself) for i = 0 to 10?

Comment: Yes ,as well ,but i think we have to get 9 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find number of such pairs (T after A in range < gap) in O(N) time using queue data structure

```
 Run through you string.
     When you meet A, add it's position to queue
     When you meet T, add queue size to result
     If queue head <= current_position - gap
        remove head
```

Comment: Thinks for the idea,but i think it will take more time infact of using the queue

Comment: Queue takes O(1) per insertion, peek and deleting, so overall time is linear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in `O(N log N).` The algorithm is as follows:

1. Store the indexes of each letter `i` in a sorted manner.  `O(N)`
2. For every index with the letter `j`, binary search for the number of indexes of the letter `i` in the range.  `O(N log N)`

In C++, this can be done by subtracting iterators. For example, in 1 iteration:

```
vector<int> indices;   <- Store indices of letter i
int index;   <- Index of a letter j
vector<int>:iterator it1 = upper_bound(indices.begin(),indices.end(),index+L);  <- Position just above the last index 
vector<int>:iterator it2 = lower_bound(indices.begin(),indices.end(),index-L);  <- Position at or below the first index
int num = it1 - it2;  <- number of indices with the letter i in the range
```

For other languages, there might be other methods of  doing this, but since I am not very well versed in terms of different programming languages, I can only give a C++ example. Basically you want to subtract the larger index by the smaller index.

You might want to look up some other applications of [binary search](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/) as well.

Comment: think you for this idea

Comment: You can even change last `indices.end()` by `it1`.